# Como imprimir linhas que tenham uma certa palavra em python?

Tags: python, string, arquivo

Estou fazendo uma prova e ela possui essa questão : "Faça um programa que receba frases e as insira em um novo arquivo chamado string.txt. Em seguida
o programa deverá fazer a leitura do arquivo e imprimir somente as linhas que possuem a palavra
Python. Além disso, o programa deverá informar a quantidade de linhas existentes no arquivo."

Já consegui inserir as linhas no arquivo e contá-las. Mas não consigo printar as linhas que tenham a palavra Python...

```
ql = 0
frase1 = str(input('Digite a primeira frase: '))
frase2 = str(input('Digite a segunda frase: '))
frase3 = str(input('Digite a terceira frase: '))

arquivo3 = open("string.txt","w")

arquivo3.write(f'{frase1}')
arquivo3.write(f'\n{frase2}')
arquivo3.write(f'\n{frase3}')

arquivo3 = open("string.txt","r")
for linha in arquivo3:
    ql += 1
    if linha in 'Python' or 'python' :
        print(linha)

    else:
        pass
print(f'Existem {ql} linhas')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta inverter os parâmetros do teste.

Original:
if linha in 'Python' or 'python' :
print(linha)

Proposta:
if 'Python' in linha or 'python' in linha:
print(linha)

Comment: caramba, só falta de atenção mesmo ahahah, obrigado!